# How do I prevent #<ObjectId..> to break my map with CongoMongo?

Tags: mongodb, clojure

using Clojure 1.3.0 with CongoMongo 0.1.7 and doing a simple (fetch-one :my_collection) return something like the following:

```
{:_id #<ObjectId 4f10d46c56bad557a7729f95>, 
 :key2 "value2",
 :etc "etc
}
```

and that `'#<ObjectId'` breaks everything but I'm surprised I cannot find anyone with the issue anywhere.

In fact I do a simple `(type *the_result_above*)` I get clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap while manually removing the `#` bit I correctly get clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: I don't get it. What is the problem? How does it break your application?

Comment: the result is clearly a map (and in fact if I remove that bit and leave everything else it says it's a map) but because of that bit it's returned as an array. Don't see why I should spend time converting an array to a map when in reality it's already a map. thanks

Comment: [PersistentArrayMap](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentArrayMap.java) is just another implementation of the map datastructure. It is not an array. Try `(class {:a 12 :b 123})` and see what does it return.  If I'm not mistaken this class is typically used for small maps. The concrete map implementation used should be transparent to you and you really shouldn't write your programs that depend on whether this or that implementation was used.

Comment: thanks Goran. The problem is that when I try to use it with another function I get a 'Don't know how to create ISeq from:' and I thought it was down to that but clearly isn't. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are not the only one with this issue. In one of my projects I created a workaround by adding the following function:

```
(defn string-id [map]
  (assoc map :_id (str (map :_id))))
```

Feed it with any map from CongoMongo, and it will replace the _id with it's string representation and return the updated map.